# Language Detection in Solr for Nutch documents

Tags: apache, solr, nutch, language-detection

How can I use Solr for language identification of documents obtained by crawling with nutch?

I installed *Nutch 1.9* and *Solr 4.8.1*. 
I added a new core, named `"core-test"`
 to solr by means of Core Admin in the Solr Admin page and I followed the steps in [Solr wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Detecting+Languages+During+Indexing) for language detection during documents indexing.

I modified the *schema.xml* in core-test/conf by adding the field

```xml
<field name="language_s" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
```

Then, I used Nutch for crawling a set of web pages by

```
crawl seed.txt Test http://localhost:8983/solr/core-test 2
```

Nutch works appropriately but the language of the documents is not identified, i.e. I don't obtain the field `language_s` when I make a query in http://localhost:8983/solr/#/core-test/query with `q` set to `":"`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the language detection of Nutch. Copy the xml tag below to `Nutch_HOME/conf/nutch-site.xml`:

`<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|language-identifier</value>
</property>`

The above tag enables the language-detection plugin bundled with Nutch. As described in [Nutch's wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexStructure), the plugin will add a field named "lang" which contains the language code of your documents.